# How can I solve this inequality for every $n$ in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am trying to find the solution to the inequality $t^{-1/n}<1$ when $n$ is an integer and $t$ is positive, however when using

```
Reduce[t^(-1/n) >= 1, t]
```

it returned an error message stating that reduce was not able to solve this inequality (Mathematica 12.0). I also tried

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0, Reduce[t^(-n^(-1)) <= 1, t]]
```

If I use

```
f[n_] := Reduce[t^(-1/n) <= 1, t]; 
f /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
```

I get the correct intervals of $t\geq1$. How can I show this for every $t>0$ and $n\geq1$ using Mathematica.

Comment: [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bt%5E%28-1%2Fn%29+%3E%3D+1%2C+t%5D) can solve this.

Comment: *Mathematica* is not yet capable of reading minds, so you need to explicitly tell it your assumptions: `FullSimplify[Reduce[t^(-1/n) < 1 && t > 1 && n ∈ Integers && n > 0, t], t > 1 && n ∈ Integers && n > 0]`

Comment: But you are basically implementing the answer and checking whether it is true. What if the answer was not available or not immediate? That is why I posed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that `n` is an integer and that `t` is positive. Include **both** of these constraints in `Reduce`

```
Reduce[t^(-1/n) <= 1 && Element[n, Integers] && t > 0, t] // Simplify

(* t^(-1/n) ∈ Reals && 
 n ∈ Integers && ((n <= -1 && 0 < t <= 1) || (n >= 1 && t >= 1)) *)
```